# Hash url and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using `angularjs` for part of my page say single component, which is used in many pages.Now my problem is hash url does not work now.

Example: I have a div#hello in my page and URL is given as Url#hello.but it does not go to that particular div just the top of the page is diaplayed.
So could you guys help me here please?

**NOTE**:The url#hello is changing to url/#hello.The page cannot be changed to angular and only that single component use angular.

**EDIT:** Thank you Stephen:) yes, of course, we need to use routing.The thing is, after page load, if we change the url back to URL#hello it works.So is it possible to do it in other way apart from Routing and `$angularscroll` ?(i.e) just from the `JS` or `jQuery` perspective ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks. I've misunderstood you. I think I have a better understanding now. Please correct me if I am wrong:

So, you're essentially trying to make a `hello` link that points to a section within the same page. When you change the url to `pageUrl#hello` the page should jump down to the section with the id called `hello`.

But the problem is that since your section has an AngularJS component that uses the `ngRoute` module, this routing functionality is making your page redirect to `pageUrl/#hello` instead of jumping to the HTML section with the `id='hello'`.

Is this correct?

---

**Solution**

If I understand your problem correctly, the solution is to check if your `ng-app='appName'` attribute is on the `body` tag. If it is, then move it down to your component's parent element.

If a hash link is a child of the `ng-app` element, then when you click it AngularJS thinks you want to redirect to another view. This is what causes the `Home` link to redirect to `pageUrl#/home`.

```html
<body ng-app="demoApp">
    <a href="#hello">Hello</a> <!-- redirects to #/hello -->
    <div id="hello"></div>

<!-- ... -->
```

So if you put the hash link outside of the `ng-app` element then it will behave as expected when you click it.

```html
<body>
    <a href="#hello">Hello</a> <!-- jumps to the 'hello' div -->
    <div id="hello" ng-app="demoApp"></div>

<!-- ... -->
```

**On Page Load**

If you want the page to jump to the `hello` div on page load, then set `window.location = '#hello'` inside your controller. Then, when you visit `pageUrl#hello`, the `hello` div should appear instead of the top of the page.

If you don't have a controller, or don't want to use one, then after your document loads, check the hash url and change it programmatically.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  if(window.location.hash == '#hello'){

    window.location = '#hello';

  }

})
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.ng-app is given for the div and not for body of  HTML.But still it does not work on page load

Comment: Hi, there. Ok, well try setting window.location = '#hello'. After this, your hash link should work on page load. I've updated my answer to clarify.